# Python,Pandas, selecting using multiple criteria: stripping quotes from string

Tags: python, pandas

I have a situation where i need to extract data from a Pandas dataframe based on a number of user defined criteria. The number of columns used in the selection process can be large so I considered creating the selection criteria as in the minimal example below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(10)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,3), columns=['a','b','c'])

query_list = []
query_string = ""  

mina = -1
minb = 2
minc = 0

query_list.append("df['a']>="+str(mina))
query_list.append("df['b']<="+str(minb))
query_list.append("df['c']<="+str(minc))

for i,q in enumerate(query_list):
    if i < len(query_list)-1:
        query_string += "("+q+")"+" & "
    else:
        query_string += "("+q+")"

print query_string

df2 = df[query_string]
```

The attempt to create df2 fails with a Key Error:

```
KeyError: "(df['a']>=-1.0) & (df['b']<=2.0) & (df['c']<=0.0)"
```

The double quotes appear to be the problem, as:

```
df2 = df[(df['a']>=-1.0) & (df['b']<=2.0) & (df['c']<=0.0)]
```

produces the desired result:

```
         a         b         c
0  1.331587  0.715279 -1.545400
1 -0.008384  0.621336 -0.720086
```

I've tried using .strip() as well as .lstrip() and .rstrip() to remove the double quotes with no success.

Any potential solution/workaround? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df

          a         b         c
0 -1.073122 -1.724574  1.476586
1  0.276805  0.007654  3.416143
2  0.054306  0.189781 -0.593007
3  1.004210  0.098396  1.488482
4  0.755500 -0.413743  0.610476
```

And

```
mina = -1
minb = 2
minc = 0
```

Then

```
df.query('a >= @mina and b <= @minb and c <= @minc')

          a         b         c
2  0.054306  0.189781 -0.593007
```

---

Constructed more dynamically

```
mins = dict(a=-1, b=2, c=0)
comp = dict(a='>=', b='<=', c='<=')
qstr = ' and '.join(['{} {} {}'.format(k, comp[k], m) for k, m in mins.items()])

df.query(qstr)

          a         b         c
2  0.054306  0.189781 -0.593007
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a much more intuitive approach than my attempt.